# Creating a database. Design help needed

Tags: sql, database-design

I am practicing python flask and I am going to make a very simple music site and am now creating the database.

I am new to databases so I just wanted help to see if the tables and relations are correct.

Also would I store multiple song ID's in the playlist_songs songID column?

```
userTable
    userID (PK), username, email, password, level
songTable
    songID (PK), songName, songArtist, songGenre, songDuration
playlistTable
    playlistID (PK), userID (FK), playlistName, playlistDescription
playlist_songs
    playlistID (FK), songID (FK)
```

Comment: Your playlist_songs probably wants an order?

Comment: i am happy with all the songs just being in order added to playlist, so would i just add the songID into that column every time they add a song?
Just thinking how i would load them all onto a page?

Comment: Looks fine. Yes, you would store multiple song ID's, but just one per row I hope. I usually add datestamps and some simple audit columns, like CreatedBy, CreatedDate, UpdateBy, UpdateDate, LastLogin etc. But, it's hardly crucial.

Comment: okay thanks, pretty sure that has cleared my query up, so for the playlist_songs it would be 1playlist id and one song, and every song in the playlist is a new row?
@Mackan

Comment: every playlist and every song combination is a new row yes. Row1: 'p1', 's1' - Row2: 'p1', 's2' - Row3: 'p2', 's1' ... and so on. Well, that's how I interpret the design, but I didn't design it ;-)

Comment: You don't currently store any order for the songs being added to a playlist, so you cannot just return them in the order they were added (the SQL engine could choose to reorder the natural on the disk to optimise table seeks, for example)

Comment: Thank you both for your help, leave a answer and i will upvote it. And for the order of the playlist i will add a time_stamp in the playlist_songs table and then the extra info in playlist.
Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As requested, I'm adding some collective info based on your question and comments.

Your design looks fine. As recommended by Rowland, it could perhaps use an order column. Something to order by. If you choose not to add this the songs will be returned in a somewhat random order for the playlist, or you could order by the `SongId` column and be guaranteed the same order at least (within a playlist). But it wouldn't be changeable.

You asked how data was entered in to the `playlist_songs` table:

```
SongTable
SongId | SongName       | ...
-----------------------------
1      | Happy Bithday  | ...
2      | Last Christmas | ...
3      | Christmas tree | ...
4      | Some song      | ...

PlaylistTable
PlaylistId | PlaylistName       | ...
-------------------------------------
1          | My Birthday songs  | ...
2          | My Christmas songs | ...
3          | All my songs       | ...

Playlist_songs
PlaylistId (FK) | SongId (FK)
-----------------------------
1               | 1
2               | 2
2               | 3
3               | 1
3               | 2
3               | 3
3               | 4
```

As you can see the `Playlist_songs` table can contain many playlists and many songs. If you query `Playlist_songs` for `PlaylistId = 2` it will return `SongId 2 & 3`, and so on.

Currently, a primary key would have to be a constraint on the two columns (a compound key). This is also where you could add an `Order` column, or just add a stand alone primary key (Id for example) and order by that.